# Node.js: null date still catching the validation for expires less than Date.now()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to make evaluation validation for finish status. However, my validation catching the "null" expiresAt value. It should be finished my evaluation successfully. However, my validation for checking the date if expires catching my expiresAt: null. Here's my code.

```
Evaluation.findOne({ _id: req.params.evaluationid }).then(evaluation => {
        if (evaluation.expiresAt < Date.now() || evaluation.status === "expired") {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Evaluation already expired, unable to finish evaluation.'
            })
        }
        if (evaluation.status !== "finished" || evaluation.status === "rejected") {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Failed to finish evaluation.',
                _id: evaluation._id
            })
        }
         else {
            Evaluation.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: req.params.evaluationid },
                { "$set": { status: "finished", updateAt: Date.now() }},
                { "new": true },
                function(err, evaluation) {
                    return res.status(200).json({
                        message: 'Evaluation finished successfully.',
                        _id: evaluation._id
                    })
            })
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json({
            name: err.kind,
            message: 'Evaluation ID doesnt exist.',
            value: err.stringValue
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you show `Evaluation`'s schema?

Comment: my default value to expiresAt is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print req.params.id in console and the condition "evaluation.expiresAt< Date.now()".
I think that the condition is not returning a value.
You should write the conditions with "()" like this.
((evaluation.expiresAt < Date.now()) || (evaluation.status === "expired")), is a good practice.
Print in your console the value of Date.now() too.
I think that the value of Date.now() is in other format that the value of date of you database.
With no-transactional database the value of date is a IsoString format.
Try to convert the value of Date.now() to IsoString. For this check the moment npm.

If your database is mongodb.
Check the documentation of queries with date like parameters of filter.
Regards.

Comment: I tried using ISOString but when the expire is feb 21 and the current feb 24. it still pushing through but it should send an error that its already expired. so its not working for me sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When calculating '<', `null` will be converted to `0`.
You need to judge `null` individually.

```js
Evaluation.findOne({ _id: req.params.evaluationid }).then(evaluation => {
        if ((evaluation.expiresAt !== null && evaluation.expiresAt < Date.now()) || evaluation.status === "expired") {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Evaluation already expired, unable to finish evaluation.'
            })
        }
        // fix the judgment of 'finished'/'rejected'
        if (evaluation.status === "finished" || evaluation.status === "rejected") {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Failed to finish evaluation.',
                _id: evaluation._id
            })
        }
         else {
            Evaluation.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: req.params.evaluationid },
                { "$set": { status: "finished", updateAt: Date.now() }},
                { "new": true },
                function(err, evaluation) {
                    return res.status(200).json({
                        message: 'Evaluation finished successfully.',
                        _id: evaluation._id
                    })
            })
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json({
            name: err.kind,
            message: 'Evaluation ID doesnt exist.',
            value: err.stringValue
        })
    })
}
```